# Nested dictionary comprehension: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I try to rewrite the following code to work with dictionary comprehension, just for fun:

```
import itertools

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    entities = f.read().splitlines()

parsed_entities = []
while entities:
    props = itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n != 'EOM', entities)
    entity = {p.split('=')[0]: p.split('=')[1] for p in props}
    entities = entities[len(entity)+2:]  # Delete and skip EOM & newline
    parsed_entities.append(entity)
```

I want to replace this line:

```
entity = {p.split('=')[0]: p.split('=')[1] for p in props}
```

With a better looking dictionary comprehension, which might look like:

```
entity = {key: value for p in props for key, value in p.split('=')}
```

When I try to do so, I get the following error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

What am I doing wrong? Using `ipdb.pm()` I saw that p is `name=yam`, which is good, but `key` and `value` are undefined.

Comment: I think the length of `p.split('=')` isn't 2.

Comment: @SamChats: sure it is. But `p.split('=')[0]` is not, and that's what is being unpacked.

Comment: @SamChats, checked it. I replaced `p.split('=')` with `print(len(p.split('=')))`, and it is 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got your point. Quite insightful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
for key, value in p.split('=')
```

because that requires every result of the `p.split()` call to have exactly **two** elements. Instead, you just have a sequence of single (string) elements, of variable length.

You'd have to wrap `p.split()` into another iterable first:

```
entity = {key: value for p in props for key, value in (p.split('='),)}
```

So now instead of:

```
['key', 'value']
```

You get:

```
(['key', 'value'],)
```

which iterates just *once*, providing two values to unpack.

However, you could just use the `dict()` callable here; it consumes an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs directly:

```
entity = dict(p.split('=') for p in props)
```

You should also try to avoid reading the whole file into memory, you can use the file as an iterable *directly*:

```
from itertools import takewhile

parsed_entities = []
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    cleaned = (l.rstrip('\n') for l in f)
    while True:
        props = takewhile(lambda n: n != 'EOM', cleaned)
        parsed_entities.append(dict(p.split('=') for p in props))
        try:
            next(cleaned)  # consume line after EOM
        except StopIteration:
            # no more lines
            break
```

Comment: Your solution absolutly works like magic, thanks! But I want to try and understand. Printing the `p.split('=')` results in `['a', 'b']`. Why you say it is a sequence of variable length?

Comment: @Infinity: `'a'` is a string of length one, but you could have `'foo'` or `'bar'` or longer or shorter strings. The `for` loop iterates over those two strings, not over the pair of them, so for `['a', 'b']` you first try to do `key, value = 'a'`. That won't work because a string of length one has just one character in it. But `key, value = 'ac'` would work, that's a string of length 2.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks :)